# How to use inner function with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, protractor

I have a piece of code on a webpage:

```
<input value="Update" class="button" onclick="return confirmUpdate();" type="submit">
```

How to access this "confirmUpdate()" function after clicking this button?

The code for protractor looks like this:

```
  it('should choose and install CrossVista package', function() {
    browser.get(`http://${serverAddress}/web/CVCM/login.do`);
    element(by.name('company_name')).$('[value="SOMECOMPANY"]').click();
    element(by.name('license_key')).$('[value="asfgastgasgf"]').click();
    element(by.value('Update')).click();
  });
```

But I don't know how to access the "OK" button from the small popup that pops after running the `confirmUpdate()` function...

I have no experience in this, completely new stuff for me, but I just need to automate a few clicks... so I don't even know what Info should I provide to widen up the topic...

Answer (score 0):

In order to click the "OK" button or interact with any sort of field on the webpage, you should open up the HTML code.

If you are in Chrome, you could **Right-Click** on the desired element then click **Inspect**. This will pull up the object in the HTML of the webpage.

Then look for how you could reference the element. Some examples:

`<div id="okBtn"> </div>`  --> `element(by.id('okBtn')).click();`

`<div class="acceptButtons"> </div>`  --> `element(by.css('.acceptButtons')).click();`

More ways depending on the structure are listed here: http://timothymartin.azurewebsites.net/protractor-cheat-sheet/

If nothing you see is very usable, **Right-Click** the object (in the HTML area) and hit **Copy Xpath**.

Then you could use, `element(by.xpath('PASTE IT HERE')).click();`